# -[GMSIndoorState didReceiveMemoryWarning:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x210b2010

Tags: ios

debug log has print:

> -[GMSIndoorState didReceiveMemoryWarning:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x210b2010

but I cannot figure out where's wrong

It seems related about take photo process,

it just crash between present actionsheet to take photo and dismiss imagePicker

so I cannot use NSZombie to debug

it happened sometimes, sometimes not. please help.

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if ([actionSheet.title isEqualToString:NSLocalizedString(@"Delete the photo has picked?", nil)]) {
        if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {
            NSLog(@"photo deleted");
            self.selectedPhoto = nil;
            self.photoLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Take One", nil);
            self.photoIsOn = NO;
            self.photoIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_icon_off_60.png"];
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Source button tapped index: %d", buttonIndex);
        if (buttonIndex != [actionSheet cancelButtonIndex]) {
            self.imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
            self.imagePicker.delegate = self;
            switch (buttonIndex) {
                case 0: //Camera
                    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
                    break;
                case 1: //Library
                    self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            [self presentViewController:self.imagePicker
                               animated:YES
                             completion:nil];
        }
    }
}


- (void)friendPickerViewControllerSelectionDidChange:(FBFriendPickerViewController *)friendPicker
{
    self.selectedFriedns = friendPicker.selection;
    [self updateSelections];
}

- (void)updateSelections
{   
    //update picked photo
    self.photoLabel.text = (self.selectedPhoto ? NSLocalizedString(@"Taken", nil) : NSLocalizedString(@"Take one", nil));
    self.photoIsOn = (self.selectedPhoto != nil ? YES : NO);
    self.photoIcon.image = (self.selectedPhoto != nil ?
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_icon_60.png"] :
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"camera_icon_off_60.png"]);
    self.sendButton.enabled = (self.textView.text != nil);
}
```

Comment: Hi Seraph J, do you fix this issue?

Comment: at the time that 1.4 released, the SDK has some bug, just update the SDK to the newest version, it will fixed.
but that's in the period of time that during 1.4.X, so recently in 1.5.X I'm not sure it's bugless or not.
hope it's helps you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably it is GoogleMaps SDK problem. It was fixed in the version 1.4.1. Please update to the latest version of the GoogleMaps.framework.
More details here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases

Comment: thanks..... I wasn't think of that way, looks like after version 1.4, it's a lot of bugs over there....